# Make sure translations JSON file has loaded before continuing to load Angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization

We're using [ng2-translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate) to implement internationalisation in an Angular application, with translations using the `.instant(...)` method to avoid the clutter of subscribing to observables.

However, `.instant` will error if the translations `JSON` file hasn't finished loading yet. Is there a way to wait until the translations file is finished downloading before continuing to load the rest of the app?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The doc explicitly say for instant : Gets the instant translated value of a key (or an array of keys). **/!\ This method is synchronous and the default file loader is asynchronous**. **You are responsible for knowing when your translations have been loaded and it is safe to use this method**. If you are not sure then you should use the get method instead.

Also, please note that you can't block angular initialisation. The angular team does NOT want you to be able to do that.

I read the code of the lib, and the use method will return you an observable anyway. So your best shot is to do in your code (given the doc example code since you didn't posted yours :

```
constructor(translate: TranslateService) {
    var userLang = navigator.language.split('-')[0]; // use navigator lang if available
    userLang = /(fr|en)/gi.test(userLang) ? userLang : 'en';

    // this language will be used as a fallback when a translation isn't found in the current language
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');

    // the lang to use, if the lang isn't available, it will use the current loader to get them
    /* Here is your observable */
    translate
        .use(userLang)
        .subscribe(res: any => 
        {
            // In here you can put the code you want. At this point the lang will be loaded
        });
}
```

So in the subscribe callback you can do whatever you want, given that the lang is load at this point. I can't help you more since you didn't posted code but if you need further help let me now.

Comment: This does make sense, however, if I subscribe to the 'translate.use' Observable, then I know my translation file has loaded, but if that file is very big, will that not mean that the UI will have blank spots until it loads?

Comment: Yes, indeed. But you don't have others ways to go. If you really don't want to have blank spots in your UI, you can set a full page loader block with an `*ngIf="!loaded"` in your app component along the main container tag, and the opposite `*ngIf="loaded"` on your main container. In your app component your define a `loaded` boolean to false, and in the subscribe callback, you set `this.loaded = true;`

Comment: Also this is not the point but if you worry about your json filesize, you can activate gzip / deflate compression for json in your webbserver, given that gzip has a really good compression rate.

Answer (score 15):

Maybe you can try to initialize a default language translation at the angular app startup.

Add this in your app.module.ts

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: appInitializerFactory,
    deps: [TranslateService],
    multi: true
  }
]


import { APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

export function appInitializerFactory(translate: TranslateService) {
  return () => {
    translate.setDefaultLang('es');
    return translate.use('es').toPromise();
  };
}
```

You can find more details here: https://mcvendrell.medium.com/configuring-ngx-translate-to-load-at-startup-in-angular-1995e7dd6fcc

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem while using `multipleTranslateHttpLoader`.

This is how I fixed it. *I had to create my own httpLoader*

```js
import { HttpBackend, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core'
import * as merge from 'deepmerge'
import { forkJoin, Observable, of } from 'rxjs'
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators'

export class MegaMultiTranslateHttpLoader implements TranslateLoader {
  constructor(private _handler: HttpBackend, private _resourcesPrefix: string[]) {}

  public getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    const requests = this._resourcesPrefix.map((prefix) => {
      const path = `${prefix}${lang}.json`

      return new HttpClient(this._handler).get(path).pipe(
        catchError((res) => {
          console.group('MegaMultiTranslateHttpLoader')
          console.error('Something went wrong for the following translation file:', path)
          console.error('Content of the error: ', res)
          console.groupEnd()
          return of({})
        }),
      )
    })

    return forkJoin(requests).pipe(map((response) => merge.all(response)))
  }
}
```

Then in your `app.module.ts` file

```js
export function HttpLoaderFactory(_httpBackend: HttpBackend) {
  return new MegaMultiTranslateHttpLoader(_httpBackend, ['/assets/i18n/', '/assets/vendors/i18n/'])
}

@NgModule({
imports: [
  TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpBackend],
      },
    }),
  // ...
]
// ...
})
```

### Notice

- I've removed the `suffix` since I'm always using .json so change it accordingly
- We're using here the `httpBackend` and not the `httpClient`
- You'll have to install `npm i deepmerge` _which where installed automatically by the [ngx-translate-multi-http-loader library](https://github.com/denniske/ngx-translate-multi-http-loader)

### Edit

Update to the latest version of the [ngx-translate-multi-http-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-translate-multi-http-loader) should fix this issue